# Integration of $(5^{3/x}-\sqrt[3]{x^8}+9)/(3x^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem: evaluate $$\int\frac{5^{3/x}-\sqrt[3]{x^8}+9}{3x^2}\mathrm dx$$

Please provide me a hint. I tried to separate to 3 parts but don't know how to integrate $\frac{5^{3/x}}{3x^2}$.

Comment: @Amzoti Yes. I mention that in the question. I need to know how to do the first of those fractions. The other two fractions I can manage. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $u = \frac{3}{x}$, and then $du = \frac{-3}{x^2} dx$. Then

$$\int \frac{5^{3/x}}{x^2} dx = \int 5^u \frac{du}{-3}$$

Comment: Thanks. But I get $5^u$ inside the integral after substitution. Could you explain how you got just $u$.

Comment: @seek By a typo.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: let

$$u = \dfrac{3}{x}$$

Comment: thanks a lot, understood :) the people here are very generous.

Comment: After what Amzoti wrote : the integral of a^x is a^x/Log[a]

Comment: Short! and Sweet! +1